# Can't get the text value of a detached element jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<p id="1">Hello there.</p>
<p id="2">To be removed.</p>
```

However, I am detaching the `<p id="2">` element and it disappears as it should. However, I can't retrieve the text value inside that `<p>` element after the jQuery `detach()` function is called on it. The jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = $('#2').detach();
    alert($('#2').val());
});
```

I can't get the text value to appear in the alert box *after* `detach()` has been called, not before. Could anyone please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. `p` elements don't have a value (that's for form fields), they have content. Use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) or [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html), not [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val).
2. You're trying to look it up a second time, but of course it won't be found. You need to use the variable you created.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var p = $('#2').detach();
       //      v----- use `text` or `html`
       alert(p.text());
       //    ^---- use the variable `p`, don't try to look it up a second time
   });
   ```

---

Side note: `#2` is an invalid `id` selector. The `id` [cannot start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `alert($(p).text());` ?

Comment: I have tried using text. But, how would I get that text value after detach() has been called on that element?

Comment: @ftom2: Yeah, just saw and fixed that.

Comment: @blackpanther: You're re-querying the DOM by doing `$("#2")` again. Use the `p` variable you created. I read right past that at first, but have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find an element in the document that you have detached.

Use the reference to the jQuery object containing the element that you have stored in the `p` variable:

```
var p = $('#2').detach();
alert(p.text());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jWb49/